# Can i move two different objects in two different moves with UIScrollView ?Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, textfield, move

I got into UIScrollView two objects,one Button and one textField.When i press textField,i need the button move upward,while the textField move downward.
How can i do this?

Comment: Seems like you didn't try to solve your task, here is no code with issue or something else, it is very poor question

Comment: you could change their "`.frame`" properties to adjust how they are positioned within the scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your UIButton below your UITextField or you can give some specific value for Y position.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
      //you can change the setAnimationDuration value, it is in seconds.
      CGFloat textFieldY = textField.frame.origin.y;
      CGFloat buttonY = button.frame.origin.y;
      CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, buttonY, textField.frame.size.height, textField.frame.size.width);
      CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, textFieldY, button.frame.size.height, button.frame.size.width);
      [textField setFrame:textRect];
      [button setFrame:buttonRect];
      [UIView commitAnimations];
      return YES;
 }
```

and same in

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
      //you can change the setAnimationDuration value, it is in seconds.
      CGFloat textFieldY = textField.frame.origin.y;
      CGFloat buttonY = button.frame.origin.y;
      CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, buttonY, textField.frame.size.height, textField.frame.size.width);
      CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, textFieldY, button.frame.size.height, button.frame.size.width);
      [textField setFrame:textRect];
      [button setFrame:buttonRect];
      [UIView commitAnimations];
      return YES;
 }
```

Instead of "button" you can use your button outlet.

**Note - I have not tested this code. Hope it will work.**